# Game theory, Kuhn tree [ extensive form of game ]

Tags: game-theory

Can someone please suggest how I can display this game in extensive form \?

A coin is biased so that the probability of heads is $ \frac{2}{3} $. The coin is tossed by Player A, who does not show it to Player B. Player A makes a claim about the outcome, and B then guesses how the coin fell. B wins $£3$ for a correct guess and nothing otherwise. If A’s claim was true then A wins $£3$. In addition, A wins a further $£6$ if B guesses heads.
 show This game in extensive form.

Comment: What does "so that the probability of heads is 22" mean? Can probability be more that 1?

Comment: the probability is 2/3, sorry that is a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here is the sketch (if I have understood the question exactly). The player $"0"$ is natural randomness and $p$ denotes on probability of revealing $Heads$ in coin toss. Also $h_i$ and $t_i$ denote the guessing strategy chosen by $A$ and $B$ respectively for $i=1,2$. Also the corresponding strategic form is:

[image]

Comment: Looks good, but I think the information set (ellipse) denoted for A should not be there, as A knows the outcome.  The information set should be there for B, who does not know the outcome.